# Redirect Console.Beep

Tags: c#, .net

How can I capture/redirect the sound produced by, say:

```
Console.Beep(400, 1000);
```

Either to some byte buffer or directly to a wav file would be fine.

I've searched, but only found ways to redirect the text output, not sounds.

Comment: Look into generally recording sounds from the sound devices, rather than redirecting the sound output of your program.

Comment: ...or are you merely attempting to generate a WAV file with a particular tone in it? If so, that's a different question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to redirect the beep sound.

`Console.Beep()` is implemented by a call to the [`Windows API Beep() function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which calls into the Sound Card hardware if it can.

You have several options:

- You could use [DirectShow's *Audio Capture* as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- You could use [an audio capture program such as described here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3400328/how-record-windows-audio-on-your-pc-or-laptop/).
- You could write [a program to generate a wav file as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2009/06/24/intro-to-audio-programming-part-3-synthesizing-simple-wave-audio-using-c.aspx).

I reckon the last of those is your best bet.